# Auto trigger craft project-config/sync on deployment

Tags: craft3, deployment, cli

So I have the following in my Composer file:

```
  "scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
      "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
      "@php craft setup/welcome"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "@php craft migrate/all",
      "@php craft project-config/sync",
      "@php craft clear-caches/compiled-templates",
      "@php craft clear-caches/cp-resources",
      "@php craft clear-caches/data",
      "@php craft clear-caches/seomatic-frontendtemplate-caches",
      "@php craft clear-caches/seomatic-metabundle-caches",
      "@php craft clear-caches/seomatic-sitemap-caches",
      "@php craft clear-caches/temp-files",
      "@php craft clear-caches/template-caches"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
      "@php craft migrate/all",
      "@php craft project-config/sync",
      "@php craft clear-caches/compiled-templates",
      "@php craft clear-caches/cp-resources",
      "@php craft clear-caches/data",
      "@php craft clear-caches/seomatic-frontendtemplate-caches",
      "@php craft clear-caches/seomatic-metabundle-caches",
      "@php craft clear-caches/seomatic-sitemap-caches",
      "@php craft clear-caches/temp-files",
      "@php craft clear-caches/template-caches"
    ]
  }
```

and on my deployment (deployHQ) I have the following SSH command:

```
cd %path% 
composer install
```

However, sync changes (project-config/sync) doesn't take effect and each time I have to manually click the button.
Any ideas what I am missing in the process?

Comment: Is there anything in DeployHQ's deployment report/log? Can you see it successfully running the sync command?

Comment: Only log I get back from DeployHQ is this;
Assume it won't log these commands as they are via the composer script?

Comment: Run these commands when I manually run composer install via SSH. 
I have just updated composer, so I wonder if that has resolved this.
I will test this out on Monday.

Comment: @TerryUpton: did you get this solved?